# Unable to load the requested file:

Tags: php, codeigniter

Any wrong with my code, I wanna show the data from DB, but I got an error here. Please, somebody, help a newbie here :')

Model:

```
<?php

class model_pelayan extends CI_Model
{       
    function cekmeja(){
    $devices = $this->db->get('devices');
    return $devices;
}

} 
?>
```

#### Controller:

```
$halaman['page'] = $page;
$this->load->view('pages/pelayan/',$page);
$this->load->model('model_pelayan');

//just adding this code, and then line above is error   
$data['devices'] = $this->model_pelayan->cekmeja()->result()    ;
$this->load->view('cekmeja',$data);
```

Comment: the exact error is?

Comment: What file that is unable to be loaded?

Comment: Show your `model_pelayan` model code

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

Here is your model function, replace it and try.

```
public function cekmeja()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('devices');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    $result = $query->result_array();

    if(isset($result) && !empty($result))
    {
        return $result;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

and this how you could call model in the controller and pass the result to the view.

```
$devices = $this->model_pelayan->cekmeja();
$this->load->view('cekmeja',['devices' => $devices]);
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look @ https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Loader.php#L327

You'll see the line `$model = ucfirst($model);`

It means your model has to start with an uppercase letter.

> This exact information is very well documented under https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html?highlight=model#anatomy-of-a-model

so basically the only thing you've to change is your filename and your model Class name to `Model_pelayan`

```
class Model_pelayan extends CI_Model
{       
    function cekmeja()
    {
        $devices = $this->db->get('devices');
        return $devices;
    }

}
```

Your controller code is totally fine - because you've to load the model with lowercase only - as you can see it [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html?highlight=model#loading-a-model)

```
$this->load->model('model_pelayan');
```